# Adding a new view to an existing module

Tags: 8, views, updating

I am trying to add a new view to an existing module. I created the view using Views UI and exported its YML to the 'config/optional' folder.  If I install the module for the first time, the view is enabled in Views UI.

When I add the view to an existing site, it won't activate no matter what I do.  I've tried clearing caches, looked for examples in core & contributed modules and searched the documentation for possible hook_update examples.  The only thing I found was in 'Create or update a View' section at https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/examples-for-database-update-scripts-using-hook_update_n-how but it's for Drupal 7.  The PHP code looks like it would work for Drupal 8 but I haven't been able to find a way to export a view as code.

Comment: Something like this is what you're looking for: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194679/putting-new-configuration-files-in-module-hook-update-n-upgrade?rq=1

Comment: @Clive That's exactly what I was looking for!!! Thanks again Clive.